# Access HTMLButtonElement inside ContentChildren with QueryList

Tags: angular

I am trying to access `HTMLButtonElement` inside the component which has `ng-content` but is not getting the Button Elements.

**TestComponent**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
template: `<div>
              <ng-content select="button"></ng-content>
           </div>`
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {

@ContentChildren(HTMLButtonElement)
buttons: QueryList<HTMLButtonElement>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.buttons.forEach(x => { //this.buttons.length is always 0
         x.classList.add('btn-primary');
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<app-test>
    <button>Button1</button>
    <button>Button2</button>
</app-multi-action-button>
```

Comment: did you tried in ngAfterViewinit?

Comment: Did you try with a reference variable?

Comment: @LogicBlower, Yes, with that also cannot access buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma623908846433166?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

According to [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren), `@ContentChildren()` searches for *"The directive type or the name used for querying"*. That means it only works for `@Component` or `@Directive` decorated elements, or the ones marked with template reference variables (none of these is applicable to your case).

What you can do is mark the div as a container, then, afterward, look for the buttons inside it using the browser's native API.

```html
<div #container>
  <ng-content select="button"></ng-content>
</div>
```

```js
@ViewChild('container', {static: true}) containerDiv: ElementRef;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  const buttons = this.containerDiv.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button");
  buttons.forEach(x => x.classList.add("btn-primary"));
}
```

[image]

## Another approach: MutationObserver

Out of curiosity: without a `{static: true}` parameter, what could we do?

There's something called `MutationObserver`, in the browser API. You can register a callback to be called whenever a selected part of the DOM changes in various aspects (attributes, nodes, values), or even the entire document if you wish.

With that in mind the below steps are what we could have done here to get a `MutationObserver` helping us (check this other [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma623908846433166-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)):

**STEP 1:** Create the function to be called when something changes in the observed object.

```js
export function buttonsObserverCallback(
  mutationsList: MutationRecord[],
  observer: any
) {
  mutationsList.map(m => m.addedNodes).forEach(n => {
    n.forEach(no => console.log(no))
  });
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for (let i = 0; i < mutationsList.length; i++) {
    if (
      mutationsList[i].type === "childList" &&
      mutationsList[i].addedNodes.length
    ) {
      mutationsList[i].addedNodes.forEach((node: Node) => {
        if (node instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
          const $button = node as HTMLButtonElement;
          if (!$button.classList.contains("btn-primary")) {
            $button.classList.add("btn-primary");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**STEP 2:** create an instance of a Mutation observer and register the above callback with it

```js
private _mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(buttonsObserverCallback);
```

**STEP 3:** get an instance of the angular component and register it to be observed

```js
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  this._mutationObserver.observe(el.nativeElement, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true, // observe the descendants too
  });
}
```

**STEP 4:** Do not forget to release the observer in the end

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
  this._mutationObserver.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: `containerDiv` is undefined. even in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Well, the content wasn't ready. Just put a `setTimout` (with no delay) wrapping the `ngAfterContentInit`, just to throw the code to the beginning of the event queue line, to be executed in the following loop. I've updated my code with that and with a Stackblitz demo.

Comment: This is the downside of touching the DOM directly. Angular methods automatically detect mutations in the DOM and refresh the query. We aren't observing anything, just querying the DOM once. By doing the search prematurely, that's what we've got. BTW, I don't like `setTimeout` in code, but this is the simplest workaround.

Comment: I cannot go with `setTimeout`

Comment: I am able to access this way `@ContentChildren('button', { descendants: true, read: ElementRef}) elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;` but still figuring out if there is a way to remove the `button` selector

Comment: When returning from lunch I'll take a look. That will be the complicated approach, but it's possible to remove that timeout there. (I'd stick with it)

Comment: In fact there's another simple approach: add `{static: true}` to the `@ViewChild`. No need for `setTimeout`

Comment: It is still `undefined`

Comment: Have you checked the stackblitz demo? It's working fine there. Do you have anything else in your template that could possibly interfere with it?

Comment: ohh yes it is working there. I am having another directive with it `*dropdownMenu` and seems not working

Comment: Maybe that alternative approach I've just added to my answer can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about querying for the `HTMLButtonElement`, but you could try to assign template reference variables to the elements. Try the following

parent.component.html

```html
<app-test>
  <button #button>Button1</button>
  <button #button>Button2</button>
</app-test>
```

test.component.ts

```js
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren('button')
  buttons: QueryList<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.buttons.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x);
      x.nativeElement.classList.add('btn-primary');
    });
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ab9ce)

Comment: This works but why not replacing `HTMLButtonElement` with `any` ?

Comment: `@ContentChildren('button', { descendants: true, read: ElementRef}) elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;` works but figuring out withou assigning `#button` selector

Comment: `HTMLButtonElement` is replaced with `any` because with template reference variables we are accessing a list of `ElementRef`s and not the `HTMLButtonElement` directly. That is why we now say `x.nativeElement.classList` instead of `x.classList`. You could also use `buttons: QueryList<ElementRef>` if you're using the `#button` reference variables.

Comment: I am not finding way without using template reference `#button`. hence, accepting. Thanks

Comment: I'll post here if I were to come across other elegant approach.